# encode byte data type from a binary file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I have a binary file and when I open it in python, the data would look like this:

```
b'\x00\x20\x00\x2A\x02\x01'
```

the data is presented in pairs. in the above example there are 3 pairs (`\x00\x20  \x00\x2A  \x02\x01`). I want to change the input file and then write it into a binary file. the change is as follows:
in every pair, if the 1st item is 0, the 2nd item will be in the output file. if the 1st item is 1, the 2nd item from the previous pair will be in the output file. if the 1st item is greater than 1, then it would be more complicated. it would depend on 2 items in the same pair. for example1, if the 1st item is 2 and the 2nd item is 1, to get the number for the output, the program goes 2 items back in the output and uses that item as the output.
example2: if the 1st item is 2 and the 2nd item is 2, to get the number for the output, the program goes 2 items back in the output and uses that item plus 1 item after that as the output.

here is the expected output:

```
b'\x20\x2A\x20'
```

I tried to that using the following code in python but did not return the expected output. since I am quite new at working with binary files, would you help me to fix it? or give me some tips to get such output?

```
data = b'\x00\x20\x00\x2A\x02\x01'

out = bytearray()
for i in range(len(data)):
    if i % 2 !=0:
        if data[i] ==0:
        out.append(data[i+1])
        elif data[i] ==1:
        out.append(data[i-1])
        elif data[i] >1:
            n = data[i]
            for j in range(n):
                out.append(n[0:j])
```

Comment: Posts that are submitted belong to the community (literally, you grant a permanent license to their use). Vandalizing potentially-valuable content is unacceptable -- and if you want to delete something that hasn't been upvoted or answered, you can just click the "delete" button.

Comment: That said, to help understand why your original code didn't work -- integers and strings are not the same type. `'\x00' == 0` is false, even though `ord('\x00') == 0` is true.